# Is it possible to store an external file rows as scalar variables and loop through it with some condition in PERL?

Tags: perl

The below code works fine and print out those rows which contain word "Street". I want to know if there is another way of doing the same without using special variable $_.
for example putting every row into a incremental scalar variable and looping every row for the same condition. I am a newbie in perl and hence it may sound stupid so sorry for trouble.
Any advice is much appreciated , thanks.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

open(fh1,"sample.file");

while(<fh1>){
    print if /Street/ ;
}
close fh1;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `incremental scalar variable`? An array?

Comment: suppose i put , @list = <fh1>, then i want to print like $list[0] to $list[$#list] with the condition. yes its an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `while(my $line = <fh1>)` if you want to avoid using `$_` though I can't imagine why you'd want to do that.

If you want to read it into an array,

```
@array = <$fh1>;
```

Then after this, you can access individual elements as `$array[0]`...`$array[N]`.

```
my @array = <fh1>;
for(my $i =0; $i<$#array; $i++){
     print $array[$i] if $array[$i] =~ /Street/
}
```

---

For a large file, reading the whole file into an array will be time and memory consuming, in comparison with consuming one line of input at a time.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much, i just wanted to know basically i came from another programming background ,i was trying to associate if it could be done in another way which my mind can accept it easily. thanks again for prompt response.

Comment: @pradeep6kumar Might be better to use foreach

Comment: Thanks i am trying some more ideas too.